# access browser default homepage from html

Tags: html, browser, anchor

From an html anchor tag, is there a way to point to the browser's default home page?

I've tried this and the page just comes up blank:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirect to Default Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the link below to redirect to your browser's default homepage:</p>
    <a href="about:blank">Go to Homepage</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<a href="/">Go to Homepage</a>`

Comment: try this `<a href="#" target="_blank" >Open New Browser Tab</a>` and if this is not what you are looking let me know .

Comment: Thanks @Rainysidewalks -  That opens another tab with the same html. It still doesn't send me to the browser's default homepage.